# Where to view custom/default objects

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects

I would think this would be something easy to find or research. All I want is to know what to type in my quickfind bar to get to my custom objects and default objects. I want to check the names of them all.

Tried typing object, custom object, tried googling.

All I want is on the salesforce site how to get to a list of my custom objects. I can see where to create new ones... just not see my current ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in Setup to search for objects in both Lightning and Classic.

## Classic

In Classic, you'll find standard objects under Customize in your Setup navigation menu, or you can type their name in the Setup quick find box to narrow down the menu. You'll find custom objects under Build: Create->Objects. The Classic Setup quick find box does not find custom objects by their names *unless* you hit Enter to perform an advanced search.

Custom objects in Classic setup:

[image]

Standard objects in Classic setup:

[image]

## Lightning

In Lightning Experience, you'll find both custom and standard objects in Object Manager in Setup, and both custom and standard object names can be searched in the Setup Search box as well as the Quick Find box in the Object Manager tab.

Filtering in Lightning Setup Object Manager:

[image]

Filtering in Lightning Setup:

[image]

Comment: Ah, Create->Objects to view my list of objects. Weird. I would not think to look under creating an object to view my existing ones. This worked, will mark as correct answer in 5 min when it lets me.

Comment: I find Lightning Setup rather more intuitive myself, although it does have its rough edges.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old questions, but you can also search for custom objects using the Schema builder.
[image]